# Need assistance with creating a stored procedure which inserts into two tables

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to create a simple stored procedure that has two insert queries. The problem is its inserting duplicates of the same record which im inserting from a javafx desktop application. here is the procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[insertIntoInvoicesAndInvLines]
    (@invoiceNumber AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
     @supplierAccountCode AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
     @theDate AS DATETIME,
     @dealNoteNumber AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
     @orderNumber AS VARCHAR(MAX),
     @quantity AS FLOAT,
     @units AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
     @packSize AS FLOAT,
     @cPaid AS BIT)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Invoices (C_invno, C_supno, D_invDate, C_delno, C_OrderNo, C_Paid)
    VALUES (@invoiceNumber, @supplierAccountCode, @theDate, @dealNoteNumber, @orderNumber, @cPaid);

    INSERT INTO InvLine (N_itemQty, C_ItemUnits, N_PkSize)
    VALUES (@quantity, @units, @packSize);
END
```

Comment: what is the problem ?

Comment: also do not forget to start your procedure with `set nocount on`

Comment: I don't think JavaFX is relevant here.

Comment: removed the fx tag ...

Answer (score 1):

You can add condition into your procedure before each insert statement. I'll assume that the invoice number column is unique.

There is a simple solution:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Invoices WHERE C_invno = @invoiceNumber)
BEGIN
    -- insert into Invoices
END
```

But you need review your tables structure - if you want consistency for you DB, you can add some constraints (e.g. unique) - it will generate errors if you try to insert some duplicates.

Comment: Could not agree more on the constraints part of your answer. +1for that